# Issue with pd.Dataframe .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I imported a .csv which is fine, but i'm having issues executing a line of code because of Str / Str issue, but then I try to make it an INT by:

```
(int(mydata) / int(mydata.loc[0]) * 100).plot(figsize = (15, 6));
plt.show()
```

but I get this error now: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DataFrame'

Comment: Use `mydata.astype(int)`instead.